# QGIS 3.22 Project transformation error

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I have installed QGIS 3.22. I got this error when I was trying to open a project.
I downloaded the .tif file.

[image]

[image]

Then clicked on Install nzgd2kgrid2005.gsb
[image]

[image]

Then, I got this error.

[image]

Comment: Either there really is rights missing to writo to the folder or different file names makes the issue. The copy command wants to copy a .gsb file but what you have is .tif. Maybe the coordinate system of the project should be edited to use gridshift file in tif format.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts. Please always include error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in 3.22, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45470 and https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44061, that is caused by PROJ.

One workaround could be to build the project from beginning in 3.22.

Or wait for the next Version (hopefully 3.22.4) since it looks like the bug is found and fixed.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help.